Visualize raster data on GIS server with standard deviation method
I would like to serve some raster files (false colored infrared orthophotos) through a map server to our client.
Both Mapserver and Geoserver is used in our GIS projects, the frontend is based on OpenLayers technology.
Raster data (gdalinfo): BigTiff, Type=Byte, LZW compression with overviews
The goal is to achieve the same result as in QGIS Desktop on a web application, in which the band min/max values are recalculated with every map canvas movement, using standard deviation method.
QGIS settings:
- Multiband color
- Stretch to MinMax with Mean +/- standard deviation x 2,00 method on updated canvas
What i've tried:
GeoServer
I've found ContrastEnhancement tag in SLD: https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#contrastenhancement
With GDAL (gdal_translate, gdaladdo) preprocessed raster. Single image with correctly ordered bands and with the following SLD tag element:
<ContrastEnhancement>
        <Histogram/>
</ContrastEnhancement>

It showed a slightly different result.
QGIS with standard deviation setting:

GeoServer WMS with histogram ContrastEnhancement:

Next thing I've found is the option to calculate raster inside SLD via Jiffle language. It seemed a bit confusing and it gave a WMS error:
<Transformation>
              <ogc:Function name="ras:Jiffle">
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>script</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>
                                          src1_dsdev = 2.0 * sdev(src1);
                                          src1_mean = mean(src1);
                                          src1_min = max(src1_mean - src1_dsdev, 0.0);
                                          src1_max = min(src1_mean + src1_dsdev, 255.0);
                                          dest[0] = max(min((src1 - src1_min) / (src1_min - src1_max) * 255.0, src1_max), src1_min);
                                          src2_dsdev = 2.0 * sdev(src2);
                                          src2_mean = mean(src2);
                                          src2_min = max(src2_mean  - src2_dsdev, 0.0);
                                          src2_max = min(src2_mean  + src2_dsdev, 255.0);
                                          dest[1] = max(min((src2 - src2_min) / (src2_min - src2_max) * 255.0, src2_max), src2_min);
                                          src3_dsdev = 2.0 * sdev(src3);
                                          src3_mean = mean(src3);
                                          src3_min = max(src3_mean  - src3_dsdev, 0.0);
                                          src3_max = min(src3_mean  + src3_dsdev, 255.0);
                                          dest[2] = max(min((src3 - src3_min) / (src3_min - src3_max) * 255.0, src3_max), src3_min);
        </ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
  </Transformation>

I couldn’t find any method in the Mapserver documentation.
Does anybody have an idea where to continue the research?
Can QGIS Server resolve this problem?
EDIT:
QGIS exported SLD code snippet for one band:
<sld:RedChannel>
                <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
                <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                  <sld:Normalize>
                    <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
                    <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">149.992</sld:VendorOption>
                    <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">191.273</sld:VendorOption>
                  </sld:Normalize>
                </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
              </sld:RedChannel>

It works fine on GeoServer, but QGIS only exports the min/max band values on the specific current canvas and gives an SLD with fixed values.
EDIT 2:
QGIS screenshot with the specific setting I would like to implement.


Could you export the QGis style as SLD and add it to GeoServer

Hi Ian! I've edited the question with an SLD snippet example. What I would like to achieve is to dynamically calculate the min/max values with the above mentioned method with every canvas movement on client side.

If you leave out the values then it will stretch to the displayed values.

I've tried the normalize and histogram method without fixed values and it did the trick with those algorithms. What I would like to achieve is the Stretch to MinMax with Mean +/- standard deviation x 2,00 method which is slightly differs from the normalize or histogram method.
In the latest question edit I attached a screenshot from QGIS with the specific settings.

MapServer doesn't use SLD internally though you can apply an external SLD through a GetMap request.  The MapServer documentation for classifying rasters is https://mapserver.org/input/raster.html
